# Img is always broken no matter the "src"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Google's React example of a "Complex Grid" (found [here](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/#complex-grid)) to make a Card Like layout.

The code looks like this:

```
return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Paper
            className={classes.paper}
            onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver}
            onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut}
            onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
            <Grid container spacing={16}>
                <Grid item>
                    <ButtonBase className={classes.image}>
                        <img className={classes.img} alt={imgAlt} src={imgPath}/>
                    </ButtonBase>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm container>
                    <Grid item xs container direction="column" spacing={16}>
                        <Grid item xs>
                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="subtitle1">
                                {cardHeader}
                            </Typography>
                            <Typography gutterBottom>{cardShortText}</Typography>
                            <Typography color="textSecondary">Platforms: {cardPlatforms}</Typography>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Typography variant="subtitle1">{cardDate}</Typography>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Paper>
    </div>
);
```

And in another class that's supposed to hold a grid of these components, I'm passing a bunch of variables as props so I can reuse the Complex Grid Component. Below is my test of that:

```
<ComplexCard
    imgAlt="alt text"
    imgPath="../img/games/testimg.png"
    cardHeader="Header"
    cardShortText="Short Description"
    cardPlatforms={[<FontAwesomeIcon key={Math.random()} size="lg" icon={faMicrosoft} />]}
    cardDate="2018"
/>
```

But no matter what I put as the "imgPath" it looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the image is broken. I have checked that path is definitely correct. What might I be missing?

Comment: try `imgPath={require("../img/games/testimg.png")}`

Comment: @ic3b3rg It says the following "Cannot find module '/../img/games/testimg.png'"

Comment: Open the developer tools of your browser and look in the network tab when you load the page: you should see the request for the image: what's wrong with the request - is it 404? Or what's wrong by with the data returned (if the request works out) - is it image data or is it some HTML error?

Comment: @ic3b3rg Wait, it actually does work when I do it directly in the component. But if I pass it off as part of props, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you add that first `/` or is it just in the error msg?

Comment: @ic3b3rg I added that. But I did it wrong. I should have done what you asked in the component that's supposed to make many of these Complex Grid components. That solved the issue. You can make it an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the fully qualified image path, use require, i.e.:

```
imgPath={require("../img/games/testimg.png")}
```